# List<> of new, on-the-fly object

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I've got a bit of code that is giving me some trouble.

I'm trying to bundle a list of images into a zip file.  The problem I'm having is that, on occasion, one of the images will be opened when it is accessed, causing an exception.

I'm pretty sure it's a timing issue, so I'm coding a 'second chance' loop to catch the images that fall through (as opposed to the existing behavior, where it halts on any error and gives back what it has thusfar).

I have the potentially erroring sections of code in a try block, as seen below

```
if (!Directory.Exists(physicalPath + "/" + fi.Description))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(physicalPath + "/" + fi.Description);
}
wc.DownloadFile(source, physicalPath + "/" + fileName);
ze = zip.AddFile(physicalPath + "/" + fileName, path);
ze.FileName = fileName;
```

'ze' is a 'ZipEntry' from the Ionic.Zip library, and 'wc' is a WebClient.

In my catch, I need to store two pieces of information: 'source' and the string that results from 'physicalPath + "/" + filename'.

I know there's a way in .NET 4 to dynamically create a new object to hold this data, but I don't recall what it's called.  This has greatly hampered my google-fu.

How can I create a dynamic object that will hold a pair of strings (preferably with property names on the variables) without creating a whole new class?

Comment: I suspect the feature you're referring to is anonymous types. Problem is, you'd have to declare the variable outside your try block for it to be accessible in your catch block, and you can't (within reasonable limits) declare a variable of an anonymous type without the initialization expression. Instead, I suggest you do what BNL suggests, and use a Tuple.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that there are significant drawbacks to all of the various solutions provided (some more than other).  You shouldn't be so quick to reject just making a new simple class to hold your data, because quite often it's actually the easiest and fastest route.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you referring to a Tuple?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx

Comment: I was not, but I did end up following this pattern.  I'd wanted something like the anonymous types dbaseman mentioned, but I don't think I could count on that code being maintainable.

Answer (score 4):

You can create an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) like this:

```
var obj = new { str1 = "something", str2 = "something else" };
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("str1: {0}, str2: {1}", obj.str1, obj.str2));
```

**Edit #1**  To make an array of the anonymous type ...

```
var arr = new[] { 
            new { str1 = "a", str2 = "b" },
            new { str1 = "c", str2 = "c" },
        };
```

**Edit #2** To make a *Generic List* out of this, you have to get a bit fancier ...

```
var obj = new { str1 = "", str2 = "" };
var type = typeof(List<>);
var listType = t.MakeGenericType(obj.GetType());
var list = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
list.Add(new { str1 = "something", str2 = "something else" });

Console.WriteLine(((dynamic)list[0]).str1);
```

Comment: How do I declare a List to hold this type?

Answer (score 1):

or a dynamic object? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx

Answer (score 1):

**How can I create a dynamic object that will hold a pair of strings (preferably with property names on the variables) without creating a whole new class?**

Use a [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx).

```
// this uses a tuple to create a generic class that holds two string values.
// We also use string.Format instead of path + "/" + fileName to generate the second value.
var zipData = new Tuple<string, string>(source, string.Format("{0}/{1}", physicalPath, fileName));
```